# How do I get the child of a child when the key is not known in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

The following code enables me to return all the **Expressions** of the current user.
In this example the following Expressions are shown in the console:

[image]

But I am not sure how to list all the titles under Expressions for the current user.
The desired outcome should be:
KIKKER, CPM2MAN

```
function f_returnUserDetails(a){
    var key;
    var childData;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { //return promise
        firebase.database().ref('/users/').orderByChild("uid").equalTo(a).on('value', function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                key = childSnapshot.key;
                childData = childSnapshot.val();
                resolve([childData, childSnapshot.key]);
            });
        });
    });
};

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid = user.uid;
    f_returnUserDetails(uid).then((dbItems) => {
        console.log(dbItems[0].Expressions);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing the following you should get the requested values:

```
  firebase.database().ref('/users/').orderByChild("uid").equalTo(a).on('value', function (snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
          key = childSnapshot.key;
          childData = childSnapshot.val();
          for (v of Object.values(childData.Expressions)) {
              if (v.hasOwnProperty('title')) {
                  console.log(v.title);
              }
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: `function f_returnUserDetails(a){
    var key;
    var childData;
    var title
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
        firebase.database().ref('/users/').orderByChild("uid").equalTo(a).on('value', function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                key = childSnapshot.key;
                childData = childSnapshot.val();
                title = childSnapshot.val().title;
                resolve([childData, childSnapshot.key, title]);
            });
        });
    });
};
`

Comment: `
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var uid = user.uid;
        f_returnUserDetails(uid).then((dbItems) => {
            console.log(dbItems[2]);
        });
    });`

Comment: The thing is that `title` isnt a child node of `Expressions` but  a child-child node.

Answer (score 0):

you have to build an array of expressions and return it in your function

```
 function f_returnUserDetails(a){
      return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + a + '/Expressions').once('value')
                .then(snapshot => {
                   let expressions = [];
                   snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot =>{
                      let expression = childSnapshot.val();
                      expression.id = childSnapshot.key;
                      expressions.push(expression);
                   }); 
                   return expressions;
                });

 }
```

and later you can this function like this

```
f_returnUserDetails(uid).then((dbItems) => {
    console.log(dbItems[0].title);
});
```

Comment: This results in an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at f_returnUserDetails.then`

Comment: I forgot the "Expressions" part. I have updated the answer